# Intellij using GUI form issue

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, intellij-idea

I'm attempting to use Intellij's GUI Form designer to design the GUI for a class project. I've never really used swing so it's proving to be more difficult than I originally thought.

Basically, i've created the GUI form and bound it to my class, I then generated the main method per online instruction. When that didn't work I attempted to use .add to add it.

this Is where I am as of now. 
https://pastebin.com/u0gcs15u

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("TicketGenie");
    frame.setContentPane(new TicketGenie().panel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

This is what the form is looking like. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/slYh3.jpg

I should also mention that I am getting a null pointer exception for the main method. Also, the class I am currently taking is programming fundamentals, this is above what we are learning but I've been trying to teach myself how to make a halfway decent GUI using java.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Intellij using GUI form issue

This not about Intellij using GUI form issue, You are getting null pointer exception because inside your TicketGenie java class on Constructor TicketGenie() where you trying add null container and component.

You Just declared JPanel container and other  component But **Forget to Initialize them**,

This is the reason you are getting null pointer exception.

```
public class TicketGenie {

    private JPanel panel;
    private JTextField firstname;
    private JTextField lastname;
    private JTextField address;
    private JTextField city;
    private JTextField state;
    private JTextField zipcode;
    private JTextField phonenumber;
    private JTextField email;
    private JTextField numberoftickets;
    private JButton submitButton;
    private JLabel firstnamelbl;
    private JLabel lastnamelbl;
    private JLabel addresslbl;
    private JLabel citylbl;
    private JLabel statelbl;
    private JLabel zipcodelbl;
    private JLabel phonenumberlbl;
    private JLabel emaillbl;
    private JLabel ticketlbl;

    public TicketGenie() {
        panel.add(firstname);
        panel.add(lastname);
        panel.add(address);
        panel.add(city);
        panel.add(state);
        panel.add(zipcode);
        panel.add(phonenumber);
        panel.add(email);
        panel.add(numberoftickets);

        panel.add(firstnamelbl);
        panel.add(lastnamelbl);
        panel.add(addresslbl);
        panel.add(citylbl);
        panel.add(statelbl);
        panel.add(zipcodelbl);
        panel.add(phonenumberlbl);
        panel.add(emaillbl);
        panel.add(ticketlbl);

        submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

> Below solution java class

```
    public class TicketGenie {

    //Initialized and declared static JPanel Container 
    static JPanel panel=new JPanel();

    //Components declared
    private JTextField firstname;
    private JTextField lastname;
    private JTextField address;
    private JTextField city;
    private JTextField state;
    private JTextField zipcode;
    private JTextField phonenumber;
    private JTextField email;
    private JTextField numberoftickets;
    private JButton submitButton;
    private JLabel firstnamelbl;
    private JLabel lastnamelbl;
    private JLabel addresslbl;
    private JLabel citylbl;
    private JLabel statelbl;
    private JLabel zipcodelbl;
    private JLabel phonenumberlbl;
    private JLabel emaillbl;
    private JLabel ticketlbl;

    public TicketGenie() {

    //Components initialized
    firstname=new JTextField();
    lastname=new JTextField();
    address=new JTextField();
    city=new JTextField();
    state=new JTextField();
    zipcode=new JTextField();
    phonenumber=new JTextField();
    email=new JTextField();
    numberoftickets=new JTextField();
    submitButton=new JButton();
    firstnamelbl=new JLabel();
    lastnamelbl=new JLabel();
    addresslbl=new JLabel();
    citylbl=new JLabel();
    statelbl=new JLabel();
    zipcodelbl=new JLabel();
    phonenumberlbl=new JLabel();
    emaillbl=new JLabel();
    ticketlbl=new JLabel();

        //Add Components to JPanel Container 
        panel.add(firstname);
        panel.add(lastname);
        panel.add(address);
        panel.add(city);
        panel.add(state);
        panel.add(zipcode);
        panel.add(phonenumber);
        panel.add(email);
        panel.add(numberoftickets);

        panel.add(firstnamelbl);
        panel.add(lastnamelbl);
        panel.add(addresslbl);
        panel.add(citylbl);
        panel.add(statelbl);
        panel.add(zipcodelbl);
        panel.add(phonenumberlbl);
        panel.add(emaillbl);
        panel.add(ticketlbl);

        submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });
    }
 }
```

`Foo Class` **JFrame frame** set ContentPane of **static JPanel panel** of `TicketGenie Class`

```
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TicketGenie");
        frame.setContentPane(new TicketGenie().panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

*Note: You need set height, weight, etc of component and set layout properties for look and feel UI*

Comment: I went through and initialized all the variables including JLabel's and im still getting a null pointer exception, I think I might be misunderstanding what your are trying to tell me but basically I went through and did this for each of them  firstname = new JTextField("MyJTextField");

Comment: You must initialize all the component before running swing GUI application, Make sure you initialized all which are declared inside **TicketGenie()**  Constructor, I'm highly recommended you to go through https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html & try these example and read and understand, You'll never face this type of null pointer component initialized issue.Beat around the bush waist your time nothing else, If it possible update then your code. where we figure out your issue.

Comment: I read into this but nothing really told me why I was getting the error, everything in TicketGenie() is initialized, I tried to initialize it in the main method but because its static that doesn't really work. (since im using) "frame.setContentPane(new TicketGenie().panel);" which makes a new instance of TicketGenie I shouldn't be getting this issue (I don't think) However Intellij is telling me that this is where im getting the null pointer exception.

Comment: I updated my answer go through it, You'll never face null pointer exception issue &  I mention my note comment inside **TicketGenie** Class, which helps you better understand.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, your advice fixed the null pointer solution. Do I still need to do this"You need set height, weight, etc of component and set layout properties for look and feel UI" even though I'm using GUI form? I was under the impression that GUI form took care of that for you.

Comment: **I was under the impression that GUI form took care of that for you.** As a java programmer you need to define design **Swing GUI** with help component properties, If you beginning to build java swing GUI there other IDE (Netbeans & eclipse..), which provide drag and drop Swing UI. Provides easy way to create java swing application. Try **Netbeans**

Comment: Thanks for the help and working with me, I'll check it out.